# Change one QueryParam in angular but keep other

Tags: angular, routes

I have this situation in which I have an url like

```
https://example.com?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Now I would like to change it to

```
https://example.com?a=1&b=2&c=4
```

I tried it with

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  queryParams: { c: 4}
};

this.router.navigate([], navigationExtras);
```

But if I do that, `c` is indeed updated, but the query params `a` and `b` are removed. So I tried to add `preserveQueryParams: true` but then it seems that you cannot change anything. Any suggestions how to just update one query param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one more property `queryParamsHandling: 'merge'` in navigationExtras to keep the unchanged queryParams:-

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: { c: 4},
    queryParamsHandling: 'merge' // keep the old queryParams if they are not updated
};
this.router.navigate([], navigationExtras);
```

**Another way:-**

Or you will need to keep the old values for the unchanged queryParams. So you can keep like:-

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: {
      ...this._ActivatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams,  // get the queryParams from the ActivatedRoute
      ...{c: 4}  // and then update what you want
    }
};
```

And then do the same process as you are doing.

To get the `queryParams` from the `ActivatedRoute` you need to inject it first:-

```
constructor(
    private _ActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute // here
) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {}

changeQuery() {
  this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { ... }});
}
```